# how to update dynamically mysqli table using where condition in oophp

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Update dynamically mysqli table using where condition is not working for me, please help me.

```
public function updateProfile($profile_picture, $username,$businessname, $town) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE profile_information set profile_picture = ?, username= ?, businessname= ?, town= ? where profile_id= ? ");

    $stmt->bind_param("ssssi",$profile_picture, $username,$businessname, $town, $profile_id);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

But statically when i do this it works i don't know why:

```
public function updateProfile($profile_picture, $username, $businessname, $town) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE profile_information set profile_picture = ?, username= ?, businessname= ?, town= ? where profile_id= 4 ");

    $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$profile_picture, $username,$businessname, $town);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

**How i call updateProfile function : in updateMyProfile.php**

```
<?php 
include './DbHandler.php';
$db = new DbHandler();
$response = array(); 
if (  isset($_POST['profile_picture']) && isset($_POST['username']) &&      isset($_POST['businessname']) && isset($_POST['town']) != '') {

    $profile_picture = $_POST['profile_picture'];
  $username = $_POST['username'];
 $businessname = $_POST['businessname'];
 $town = $_POST['town'];

  $response = $db->updateProfile( $profile_picture, $username,     $businessname, $town);
}  ?>
```

**My html form**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

   <body>
<form name="uploadForm" method="post" action="updateMyprofile.php" >    
 <label>profilep</label>  <input type="text"name="profile_picture" ><br><br>
<label>Uname</label>  <input type="text" name="username" ><br><br>
 <label>BName</label><input type="text" name="businessname"><br><br>
 <label>Town </label>   <input type="text" name="town" ><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </form>  
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what i do to to avoid that error and call that function is the following but also doesn't work even though error disappeared.   `$response = array(); 
if (  isset($_POST['profile_picture']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['businessname']) && isset($_POST['town']) && isset($_POST['profile_id'])!= '') {
     $profile_picture = $_POST['profile_picture'];
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $businessname = $_POST['businessname'];
     $town = $_POST['town'];
  $response = $db->createProfile($profile_picture, $username, $businessname, $town, $profile_id);
}`

Comment: The answer posted by @scaisEdge was correct in that you do not pass the `profile_id` as a parameter to the function nor make it available as a global variable within the function. By hard-coding the value of `4` you negate the need for the variable which is why it works. IF you are POSTing `profile_id` then you should pass it as a parameter or generate the variable from the POST array within the function

Comment: I don't really know how i can generate the variable from the POST array within the function . i need your help . now with the codes above no error but no update in my table anytime call that function

Comment: How can we possibly tell you how to get this variable with the information you give us?

Comment: what i need is to update ,$profile_picture, $username,$businessname, $town  according to appropriate $profile_id . dinamically withouth writting 1,2 ,.. as  profile_id. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to pass the profile_id to your function or generate within the function - either way it needs to be available so something like this might help.

```
$response = array();
if( isset( $_POST['profile_picture'],$_POST['username'],$_POST['businessname'],$_POST['town'],$_POST['profile_id'] ) ) { 

    $profile_picture = $_POST['profile_picture']; 
    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $businessname = $_POST['businessname']; 
    $town = $_POST['town'];
    $profile_id=intval( $_POST['profile_id'] );

    $response = $db->createProfile( $profile_picture, $username, $businessname, $town, $profile_id );
}



public function createProfile( $profile_picture, $username, $businessname, $town, $profile_id ) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("update `profile_information` set `profile_picture`=?, `username`=?, `businessname`=?, `town`=? where `profile_id`=?;");
    if( $stmt ){
        $stmt->bind_param( "ssssi", $profile_picture, $username, $businessname, $town, $profile_id );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

---

Judging by the name of the function alone `createProfile` it's entirely possible that whay you need to do is actually use an `insert` statement as opposed to an `update` statement - you hint that you do not have the `profile_id` so that supports the notion that you need to generate the profile rather than update. In that case perhaps the following:

```
$response = array();
if( isset( $_POST['profile_picture'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['businessname'], $_POST['town'] ) ) { 

    $profile_picture = $_POST['profile_picture']; 
    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $businessname = $_POST['businessname']; 
    $town = $_POST['town'];

    $response = $db->createProfile( $profile_picture, $username, $businessname, $town );
} else {
    echo "One or more required variables are NOT in the POST array!"
}


public function createProfile( $profile_picture, $username, $businessname, $town ) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("insert into `profile_information` set `profile_picture`=?, `username`=?, `businessname`=?, `town`=?;");
    if( $stmt ){
        $stmt->bind_param( "ssss", $profile_picture, $username, $businessname, $town );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

If this does not help then please either update your question to include all relevant code ( including the form ) or try harder to explain what the actual problem is after checking the php error log.

Comment: I am sorry sir , this does not make any change

Comment: When I look at this the function is called `createProfile` which suggests that you should be using an `insert` statement rather than an `update` statement. Is it correct that the profile does not yet exist and that you are trying to actually create it?

Comment: It was a problem of naming the function,is just to update because profile is already there, i updated my question by changing function name and adding html form

Comment: Include a hidden field called `profile_id` with the value of `profile_id` from the db - that way it would get included in the post array when you submit the form and all would be well. I notice though in your form that there are no values for the given input fields - usually these would be pre-populated with teh existing values in the database so the user can update the details rather than enter new details